# ASP Textbox OnTextChanged is not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, c#-3.0

The textbox(text1) keep on changing time with below javascript, While changing the time I need to do some task in textbox change event in the code behind, I tried OnTextChanged  with autopostback = true which does not work while changing the time, but it works if i change manually anything in the textbox(text1), i want to fire onTextChanged while changing time. Kindly help.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function timedCount() {
        var dt = new Date()
        document.getElementById("text1").value = dt.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + dt.toLocaleTimeString();
        window.setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);
   }
 timedCount();
     </script>
```

Comment: Add `document.getElementById("text1").change()` before `setTimeout` to fire onchange event and postback.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kudryashev for solution, but i get some error "0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'change'" Please help

Comment: Sorry. Of course `document.getElementById("text1").onchange()`.

Comment: It's works, Thanks Again Mr.Alex Kudryashev :)